# Relacionamento N para N com 4 tabelas no laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Boa tarde pessoal,
comecei a utilizar o framework laravel faz pouco tempo e estou com dificuldades em implementar um relacionamento N p/ N utilizando 4 tabelas distintas.
O cenário é o seguinte; um usuário pode ter vários papéis em vários módulos distintos, exemplo:o usuário  João pode ser administrador no modulo de vendas e operador no módulo de compras, gerente no módulo de controle de usuários e assim por diante, além de também poder ter mais de um papel em um mesmo módulo.
As tabelas são: Usuário; Papel; Modulo e Atuação, onde atuação possui apenas a chave primária e as chaves estrangeiras das demais tabelas conforme a imagem a baixo: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esses são os meus modelos.
**Usuario**

```
    lass Usuario extends Model{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table='usuario';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['foto', 'nome', 'email', 'senha'];
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function atuacoes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Modules\controleUsuario\Entities\Atuacao');
    }

}
```

**Papel:**

```
    class Papel extends Model{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table='papel';
    protected $fillable = ['nome','descricao','created_at','deleted_at'];
    public $timestamps=false;
    protected $dates = ['data'=> 'm-d-Y'];

    public function atuacoes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Modules\controleUsuario\Entities\Atuacao');
    }


}
```

**Modulo:**

```
    class Modulo extends Model{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table='modulo';
    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'icone'];
    public $timestamps=false;

    public function atuacoes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Modules\controleUsuario\Entities\Atuacao');
    }
}
e por fim **Atuacao**<br><br>

    class Atuacao extends Model{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table='atuacao';
    protected $timestamps=false;

    public function usuario()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Modules\controleUsuario\Entities\Usuario');
    }

    public function papel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Modules\controleUsuario\Entities\Papel');
    }

    public function modulo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Modules\controleUsuario\Entities\Modulo');
    }
}
```

A minha dificuldade é saber como associar e mostrar todos os papéis e seus respectivos módulo de um usuário. Se alguém puder dar uma luz eu ficaria imensamente grato, desde já obrigado

Comment: Eu faria um classe Atuação e ligaria 1 para N todas as que se relacionam, porque você pode controlar esses dados melhor, N para M é bom no caso quando possui somente as chaves, já no seu caso até chave primária tem ... !!! será que não seria melhor? parece também que tem algo errado na modelo de entidade relacionamento, eu verificaria tudo isso. Parece que você até fez isso nas suas relações... kkk

Comment: Esse modelo não tá sendo usado no momento, foi só pra ilustrar, nem tá todos os campos preenchidos.  Mas msm assim obrigado por nada

Comment: A sua duvida deveria ser melhor explicado, já visto que o modelo (MER) e as relações praticamente são como ilustrados. "Obrigado por nada" soa como irônia, mas, o que não ficou claro foi sua pergunta ... [Tem a documentação que explica tudo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent) como gravar, alterar, excluir e incluir e como deve ser feitas as relações.

Answer (score 0):

Você já possui os relacionamentos feitos com base nisso, basta acessá-los.

```php
foreach($usuario->atuacoes as $atuacao)
{
   echo 'Modulo: ' . $atuacao->modulo->nome . '<br />';
   echo 'Papel: ' . $atuacao->papel->nome . '<br />';
   echo '------------------ <br />';
}
```

**Dica**: Você pode aproveitar a funcionalidade de [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) do Laravel para para sempre trazer os relacionamentos nas queries do model de atuação tornando-as mais eficientes. Veja o model com essa propriedade.

```php
class Atuacao extends Model{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'atuacao';

    protected $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The relationships that should always be loaded.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['papel', 'modulo'];


    public function usuario()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Modules\controleUsuario\Entities\Usuario');
    }

    public function papel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Modules\controleUsuario\Entities\Papel');
    }

    public function modulo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Modules\controleUsuario\Entities\Modulo');
    }
}
```

Vale a pena dar uma olhada também em [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

Comment: Valeu cara, tinha esquecido de comentar mas era isso mesmo. Muito obrigado.